# Is there any benefit in having CNNIC certificates installed, if you're not in China?

Tags: certificates, web-browser, man-in-the-middle

All modern browsers/OS come with root certificates from the China Internet Network Information Center. AFAIK these certificates are required for computers sitting behind the Great Firewall to function properly.

Personally I don't live in China and I don't go to Chinese sites since I simply don't speak the language. Thus I don't see any benefit of having these certificates installed. The drawbacks are quite clear however, since China is known to have issued fraudulent Google certificates ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Internet_Network_Information_Center#Fraudulent_certificates), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/316oaj/psa_chinas_cnnic_issues_false_certificates_in/)). Is there any reason for me to keep CNNIC certificates on my computer? Could I experience problems with legitimate sites if I remove those?

Answer (score 5):

If you **don't** use `Chinese websites and internet-based products`, you won't need to worry about removing them; you are unlikely to experience problems with legitimate websites by removing these dodgy certificates.

I used to *live* in China, and I never used any of CNNIC's certs outside of a virtual environment.

Legitimate browsers - [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/03/23/revoking-trust-in-one-cnnic-intermediate-certificate/) and [Chrome](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2015/03/maintaining-digital-certificate-security.html) for example - are excluding these certificates as a result of fraud. Get rid of them.